# Apache airflow backfill automatic date

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a DAG which I want to use for backfilling my database table.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.postgres_operator import PostgresOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 4, 1),
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
}

dag = DAG(dag_id='airflow_backfill', default_args=args, schedule_interval='@daily')

"""
    Task for inserting data per day
"""

task1 = PostgresOperator(
    task_id='insert_new_row',
    postgres_conn_id='aws_pg',
    sql="INSERT INTO airflow_test(date_at) VALUES('2018-04-01')",
    dag=dag,
)

task2 = PostgresOperator(
    task_id='update_team_name',
    postgres_conn_id='aws_pg',
    sql="UPDATE airflow_test SET team_name = (SELECT team_name FROM teams ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1) WHERE team_name is NULL",
    dag=dag,
)

task1.set_downstream(task2)
```

I am inserting one row in database from 1st of April, 2018 but the problem is that I am giving the date_at variable hard coded.

My question is, is there any way by which I can give the date of backfill as the value of insertion? I want to set the value of 'date_at' automatically while doing the backfilling but haven't found any airflow environment/config variable from which I can get the backfill date automatically.

I am using apache airflow 1.9.0. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

EDITED: You should be able to use a jinja template to grab the variable execution_date:

```
task1 = PostgresOperator(
    task_id='insert_new_row',
    postgres_conn_id='aws_pg',
    sql="INSERT INTO airflow_test(date_at) VALUES('{{ ds }}')",
    dag=dag,
)
```

https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#default-variables

Comment: I'd recommend using `{{ ds }}` because it will format the output into `YYYY-MM-DD` as requested. With `execution_date` being a datetime I am not so sure about formatting.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but isn't {{ ds }} today's date time stamp? For the execution date you can use {{ execution_date }}.strftime(%Y-%m-%d)??

Comment: From the quoted page: `{{ ds }}`: the execution date as YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Thanks. Knew it was possible. Have not experimented with the Jinja templates too heavily. Edited the answer to reflect your input.